# Arbitrary domain mapped to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I currently have an app service that is accepting wildcard subdomains with no issues:

```
*.mydomain.com
```

Maps to anysubdomain:

```
test.mydomain.com, bob.mydomain.com, tom.mydomain.com, etc.
```

But what I need now is to be able to point any other domain to my subdomain, allowing others to CNAME to me:

```
shortcut.otherdomain.com > otherdomain.mydomain.com
```

The idea being that someone can use any domain they have to create a cname that points to my subdomain, white labeling to a degree.

If I add the otherdomain.com as hostname it works as expected, but I am hoping to avoid having to add a hostname everytime I am going to add another user.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work. Azure App Service uses IIS servers in the background. These servers are in a shared environment where IP addresses are shared. The only way for it to know what site a request is headed for is to look at the URL they are accessing. And that requires that the URL is registered on the App Service so that it can find it.

Comment: yeah, seems that way. I think I'll have to use the API to add it as needed.